# Why does MySQL give error while trying to insert datetime '2019-08-13 19:00:00'?

Tags: mysql

While trying to insert a value into a DATETIME field I get the error:

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '​2019-08-13 19:00:00' for column 'my_date_time' at row 1

The insert looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`my_date_time`) VALUES('​2019-08-13 19:00:00');
```

The table is along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `my_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

PS: This is a MySQL 8 database.

Comment: how does your `my_date_time` look like? PS. Your whole table

Comment: There is a non printing character before the last bracket..

Comment: im reading that it's a bug with some numbers

Comment: That should actually work if the column is an actual DATETIME. You should try to retype the query without copy-pasting to prevent non printing character mess, if ever responsible for your problem.

Comment: Just to clarify what @P.Salmon said, you have a U+200B "Zero-Width Space" character just in front of your year that should be removed.

Comment: @P.Salmon You are correct. Thank you all for comments. You can convert your comment to an answer so that I can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

@P.Salmon (and @phatfingers) said in comments and answered:

> you have a U+200B "Zero-Width Space" character just in front of your
>   year that should be removed

.